# Cypress intercept, detect how many times API was called

Tags: reactjs, cypress, cypress-testing-library

I'm trying to detect how many times an API endpoint is called when running tests with Cypress, I'm stubbing out the endpoints with cy.intercept(). My code is like so:

```
cy.intercept("POST", "api/cancel/**", {
  statusCode: 200,
}).as("cancel_contribution");

cy.intercept("PATCH", "/api/case/**", {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: {"message": "success"}
}).as("create_case_in_salesforce");

cy.visit("/");
cy.findByText("Manage recurring contribution").click();

cy.get('[data-cy="Cancel recurring contribution"]').click();
cy.findByText("Confirm cancellation").click();

cy.wait("@create_case_in_salesforce");
cy.wait("@cancel_contribution");

cy.get('[data-cy="cancellation_message"]');

expect('@create_case_in_salesforce').to.have.been.calledOnce;
expect('@cancel_contribution').to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

I'm trying to make sure these endpoints only get called once during the test run, but the last two lines are not valid, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@alias.all` feature of Cypress for this.

```js
cy.wait("@create_case_in_salesforce");
cy.wait("@cancel_contribution");

cy.get("@create_case_in_salesforce.all").should('have.length', 1);
cy.get("@cancel_contribution.all").should('have.length', 1);
```

[For more details see this thread](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/16655)

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a mixture of async (`cy.`) and sync(`expect`) code. You can simply wrap the `expect`'s in a `.then()` command.

```
cy.intercept("POST", "api/cancel/**", {
  statusCode: 200,
}).as("cancel_contribution");

cy.intercept("PATCH", "/api/case/**", {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: {"message": "success"}
}).as("create_case_in_salesforce");

cy.visit("/");
cy.findByText("Manage recurring contribution").click();

cy.get('[data-cy="Cancel recurring contribution"]').click();
cy.findByText("Confirm cancellation").click();

// add .then() to check was called once
cy.wait("@create_case_in_salesforce").then(req => {
  expect('@create_case_in_salesforce').to.have.been.calledOnce;
})
// add .then() to check was called once
cy.wait("@cancel_contribution").then(req => {
  expect('@cancel_contribution').to.have.been.calledOnce;
})

cy.get('[data-cy="cancellation_message"]');
```